# Should HTML or Markdown be passed to /questions/{id}/edit?

Tags: support, editing, write-access

I'm making an app that supports editing questions. Should HTML or Markdown source be passed to the body parameter of [`/questions/{id}/edit`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/edit-question)?

Answer (score 5):

Markdown. While you could use HTML (just like you can in posts), each time you use HTML instead of Markdown to format a post, Evan Carroll rapes a little kitten and sticks another needle in his Jeff Atwood voodoo doll.

Comment: And for every `<br>`, *ten* ***million*** **tiny** ***cute*** `little` *puppies* ***DIE*** ARRRGGHHHHHGbhfkjhdndfuhwi9gy89fwe74r